# MySQL failing to start

Tags: mariadb

I am using MySQL installed as a service in XAMPP, which is having trouble starting up after a computer restart. It starts up fine when manually triggered. This is the error log after the event:

```
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.12
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 2G, instances = 2, chunk size = 128M
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.27 started; log sequence number 27154181274; transaction id 1124623844
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2023-10-12 21:20:32 0 [Note] C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.27-MariaDB'  socket: ''  port: 3306  mariadb.org binary distribution
2023-10-12 21:20:35 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Retry attempts for reading partial data failed.
2023-10-12 21:20:35 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Tried to read 16384 bytes at offset 178061312, but was only able to read 0
2023-10-12 21:20:35 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 203 in a file operation.
2023-10-12 21:20:35 0 [Note] InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/operating-system-error-codes/
2023-10-12 21:20:35 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: File (unknown): 'read' returned OS error 403. Cannot continue operation
231012 21:20:35 [ERROR] mysqld got exception 0x80000003 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
```

I already run a mysqlcheck on all tables and all of them were OK. I also reinstalled xampp from the group up, but the error persisted.

Comment: try to repair the tables https://mariadb.com/kb/en/repairing-mariadb-tables-for-sql-server-users/